# como obtener las propiedades de un objecto dinamicamente en dapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper

Yo tengo un objeto llenado apartir de dapper y extrae la informacion de un sp que trae una tabla dinamicamente, el problema es cuando quiero obtener el nombre de cada atributo del objeto.

Asi obtengo los datos de la tabla.

```
public List<object> GetFirstTableBk(string Table, string? NRO_IDENTIFICACION, string? NUMERO_PRODUCTO, string? NUMERO_PRODUCTO_RELACIONADO, string? NUMERO_IDENTIFICACION_REL, int FLAG)
        {
                var connectionString = _CRMInterfazDbContext.Database.GetConnectionString();
                var storedprocedure = "CRMUPLOADMANAGER_GET_FIRST_TABLE";

                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    var STG_BK = connection.QueryAsync<object>(
                        storedprocedure,
                        new
                        {
                            TABLE = Table,
                            NRO_IDENTIFICACION = NRO_IDENTIFICACION,
                            NUMERO_PRODUCTO = NUMERO_PRODUCTO,
                            NUMERO_PRODUCTO_RELACIONADO = NUMERO_PRODUCTO_RELACIONADO,
                            NUMERO_IDENTIFICACION_REL = NUMERO_IDENTIFICACION_REL,
                            FLAG = FLAG
                        },
                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        ).Result.ToList();

                    return STG_BK;
                }
        }
```

Prueba

```
public void Nombre(List<object> datos)
        {
            Type tipo = null;
            PropertyInfo[] propiedades = null;
            tipo = datos.GetType();
            propiedades = tipo.GetProperties();
            foreach (var propiedad in propiedades)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(propiedad.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Me da otra cosa que es Capacity, Count y Item en el console.writeline, pero en los datos puedo ver los datos como se muestra en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por otra parte puedo ver los atributos del objeto pero no puedo mostrarlos en console.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si te estoy entendiendo bien, ¿quieres obtener `TABLE, NRO_IDENTIFICACION, NUMERO_PRODUCTO, NUMERO_PRODUCTO_RELACIONADO, NUMERO_IDENTIFICACION_REL, FLAG ` ? Y de ser ese el caso, ¿qué error te da cuando ejecutas `public void Nombre` ?

Comment: Y por otro lado, ¿por qué usas `datos` y no `datos[0]` ?

Comment: @fredyfx es dapper.. esos son los parametros... lo que no se, es como esperas saber que cosas vas a mostrar donde si tu objeto devuelto es magico y siempre diferente.... igual, te esta devolviendo todo en un solo string donde lo estas mostrando... es un array de una sola fila.. que se ve que es lo que devuelve el SP

Comment: datos[0] no me devuelve nada en el console y vi otro atributo de datos que son las keys y me muestra los nombre de los atributos